# Under what circumstances a beta site can be closed?

Tags: discussion, beta-sites

I've been looking between questions, e.g. [How to determine the close date of a closed beta site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244024/how-to-determine-the-close-date-of-a-closed-beta-site) However, it is not clear to me the procedure or the circumstances under which a beta site is closed.

Comment: See also: [Pruning season](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/)

Comment: See also: [Merging season](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/merging-season/)

Comment: See also: [When a Site Grows Quiet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/)

Comment: I don't think there are any fixed rules for this. Each site is being evaluated on its own and the decision varies based on many factors.

Answer (score 2):

> However, it is not clear to me the procedure or the circumstances
>   under which a beta site is closed.

Whether a Beta Site is closed or not appears to be at the sole discretion of Stack Exchange Inc. So there is no clear-cut reasons for why a site may be closed or not. However, there are factors which may help you in determining if a beta site has a better chance at being closed or graduated to a full site.

For example, you can click on the Beta Site you want, and see a breakdown of statistics. For example, here's [Aviation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation) :

[image]

Red is bad, orange is OK, and green is good.

The more red, the more likely a beta could be closed ***probably***. The more green, the more likely a beta gets to be a graduated site ***probably***.